# Python function assignment outside class definition causes argument exception

Tags: python, function-pointers

I am working in a dynamic programming environment where I might need to define (or redefine) a class function. So consider this for example:

```
def func(self):
    print("hello2 \n")

class ManClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def func1(self):
        print("hello1\n")

a = ManClass()

a.func1()
hello1

a.func2 = func
>>> a.func2()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: func() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

If func2() had been defined inside the class - a.func2() would have been interpreted as ManClass.func2(a) - but now that I am assigning it outside, it seems to expect an argument. How do I fix this, but more importantly, why this difference in how the two definitions are interpereted ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't add `func` to the class, you added it to an instance.  Try `ManClass.func2 = func` instead.

`a.func2 = func` adds `func` to the `a` instance of the class as an instance attribute named `func2`, not as an instance member method (which is really just special handling for callable members on the underlying class object).

Alternatively, you can also add a member method to a single instance using `MethodType`, as @jonrsharpe points out in his answer.

Comment: Oh snap, you're right. Class and instance attributes/functions are 'different'. I should've known what I was doing wrong. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

This is the difference between a function and a bound method, where "bound" refers to the instance `self`. To fix your problem, you need to make the standalone function `MethodType`:

```
from types import MethodType

a.func2 = MethodType(func, a)
```

This binds the `func` to the `ManClass` instance `a`, allowing it to access any instance attributes. Note that this *only affects `a`*, other `ManClass` instances will retain the original class definition unless similarly patched.

When you simply attach the function

```
a.func2 = func
```

you can still access it:

```
a.func2(None) # will print "hello2 \n"
```

But it doesn't get the implicit object instance `self` parameter and just treats it as a standard positional argument.